# Geting values from products in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute

I need help with getting some values out of my code.So I have my configurable product and it is based on a global attribute "size", it has its own associated products which are the same product in different sizes. I need to somehow call a model or something that will give me the associated products and their label for the attribute "size" for example "xxl".
What I did so far was to get all child products. But the this size value is an **Int**, and there is no size label variable.

Another thing I'd like to add if it helps: the size variable from child products and the value_index from "size" options are the same.

UPDATE

This is the code and need to insert the label in it and to get it displayed in a foreach as a li element

```
$product1= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->product_id); 
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                         ->getUsedProducts(null,$product); 

foreach($childProducts as $child) {

    print_r($child->getId()); 
    print_r($child->getsize()); 

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I gave you the answer just below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute("size")->getSource()->getOptionText("your_id");
```

Comment: glat it helped.

Comment: @JulienLachal How to do this in M2?

Comment: @Joey I don't know, haven't touched Magento in a while, but a quick search will yield results for sure

Comment: @JulienLachal I tried. couldn't find what I needed. thanks anyways